# Does /NOCANDY avoid any adware-related activities with OpenCandy?

Tags: installer, adware, winscp

OpenCandy claims that using the `/NOCANDY` switch when using a OpenCandy-affiliated installer allows you to avoid opencandy.

1. Should I take their word for it?
2. If not, can anyone independent of OpenCandy and their affiliates verify that `/NOCANDY` works?

**Background:** About to install WinSCP onto a fresh Windows installation, and found out that new versions have OpenCandy associated with their installer. For the sake of balance, no longer existing WinSCP's FAQ on OpenCandy claim about `/NOCANDY` to be working, but the same boilerplate appears on other OpenCandy web sites.

If the OpenCandy people are offended by the tag "spyare": sorry, but it's the main tag here, rather than "adware".

Comment: here's a fun thread on the Miro forums: [full thread](http://getsatisfaction.com/participatoryculturefoundation/topics/opencandy), [miro backpedal #1](http://getsatisfaction.com/participatoryculturefoundation/topics/opencandy#reply_690450), [opencandy evangelist speaks](http://getsatisfaction.com/participatoryculturefoundation/topics/opencandy#reply_1129423) ... and in the interest of fairness, [opencandy's privacy policy](http://www.opencandy.com/privacy-policy/).  the Miro thread hits the how/what/where; doesn't mention */NOCANDY* but does talk about *OpenCandy_Why_Is_This_Here.txt*.

Comment: gonna go ahead and retag "adware" ... they claim to be more like AdSense than a by-the-Wikipedia-definition [adware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adware), but i think AdSense is really a form of web-based-adware, so it seems a bit more accurate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ended up installing a different SFTP client (Tunnelier) instead.

Answer (score 4):

I just downloaded ImgBurn, another program that has OpenCandy in the installer.  First I ran the installer normally, and saw the OpenCandy portion offering a 3rd-party program.  Then I quit the installer, and then opened up a command prompt (using Run as Administrator), and ran the installer with the /NOCANDY switch, and never saw the OpenCandy portion offering any 3rd-party programs.  So it seems the /NOCANDY switch does work.

There are a couple other ways to prevent OpenCandy from installing any 3rd-party programs, as mentioned in their [FAQ](http://www.opencandy.com/faqs/#avoid):

```
* Beginner: disconnect your internet connection (beware some software needs the internet to complete its install)
* Intermediate: run the OpenCandy powered installer from the command-line with /NOCANDY
* Advanced: add a domain block in your firewall for *.opencandy.com
```

In addition, with ImgBurn there are a couple more options to install while avoiding OpenCandy.  These options may or may not work with WinSCP or any other software that comes with OpenCandy:

1) Perform an NSIS silent installation using the following command (mentioned in this [post](http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?/topic/21631-to-those-who-are-unhappy-about-2580-being-bundled-with-opencandy/)):

```
SetupImgBurn_2.5.8.0.exe /S /D=C:\Program Files\ImgBurn
```

2) Use [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to open the installer and extract out the program files (mentioned in this  [post](http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?/topic/21986-opencandy-really-bad-move/?p=149750)).

Additionally, some programs offer 2 versions of the installer - one with OpenCandy and one without.  For example, CDBurnerXP does this, but when you go to their [download](https://cdburnerxp.se/en/download) page, it isn't immediately obvious that they have a version without OpenCandy.  You have to click on "More download options" to see it.

Finally, if a program has a portable version, you can use that and you'll be sure to avoid OpenCandy, since portable versions don't have installers.

Comment: Does lowercase `/nocandy` works?